# How to use Taglet or Tag in Eclipse with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, tags, javadoc, taglet

I'm trying to use the Taglet or Tag for my project because I need to create new kind of tags in my javadoc. But I'm not finding any example useful to start.
  What do I need to know is if exist any good example of the usage. I'm not finding videos teaching about it. Just the documentation at [Oracle API -](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#tag) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#tag. 
  Any tip will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Taglet documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) contains a small but explaining example to get started with. A step-by-step guide with some more examples can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3085991/Javadoc-Programming.htm).